# Error installing nio4r

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Help me, please. I'm try to install gem nio4r, but have error with this logs:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nio4r:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1/ext/nio4r
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20161020-13985-1c6zxok.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nio4r-1.2.1/gem_make.out
```

I have ubuntu 16.04, ruby 2.3.0, rails 5.0.0.1.

(with some other gems I have similar error (gem bcrypt))

What I must did to fix this bug? Thank's!

Comment: You are missing dev tools. Install ruby-dev and make using apt get : sudo apt-get install ruby-dev and sudo apt-get install make. If it still fails, you'll need to install dev tools for compilers individually. If you are on a Mac, install xcode and command line tools.

Comment: @Sam, thanks for the tip. I had xcode installed, but I had to update it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

At first try to install build essentials:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch
```

and if still don't work try to install ruby-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

regards

Comment: the below method helps me

Answer (score 8):

I am on mac and I fixed it by typing the following code

```
xcode-select --install
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 3):

The root cause of this error message for me was that Xcode updated and I had not accepted the new license agreement yet, so (for some reason) it restricted access to CLT (Command Line Tools -- this is what the `xcode-select --install` command installs).

If you already have CLT installed, you may need to run the following to get them to work:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

This is what fixed my issue; I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.1.0 works with

`sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev`